# Is there a way to create an Excel query parameter for a variable?

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel

I'm using a Query to bring some data to Excel, but there are too many lines, and the file is over 70 MB, crashing several times.
I need the values resumed by month, where someone fill the month in a Excel cell and the Excel Query updates with that value.

I tried to do something but didn't get the results I expected
The query I tried below:

```
DECLARE @Month Varchar(2);

SET @Month = ?

select distinct C.Code as ResourceCode, C.Name as ResourceName, sum( case when B.Code = '069' then MovQty * -1 else MovQty end) QTY, 
B.Code as MovCode, B.Name as MovType from TBLMovEv A

inner join TBLMovType B on A.IDMovType = B.IDMovType

inner join TBLResource C on C.IDResource = a.IDResource

inner join TBLProduct D on D.IDProduct = A.IDProduct where

year(DtMov) = 2021

and Month(DtMov) = @Month

and day(DtMov) < (case when Month(getdate()) <> @Month then day(getdate()) else 32 end)

and B.Code in ('068', '069')

and C.Code NOT like '[CKLOM]%'

and C.Code not like '[ABQ][E][M]%'

and MovQty <> 0

GROUP BY B.CODE, B.NAME, C.CODE, C.NAME, DtMov

ORDER BY C.Code
```

My problem is that I want that day could be < 32 when the Month parametrized is different from the getdate Month, and Excel isn't allowing me to set the parameter inside the case when statement.

I'd like to know if there is a way that I could set the @Month variable to parameter, or a workaround.

I also tried to get a column with de month only, and then filter through an excel formula, but it still gets something close 10.000 lines, which I want to avoid.
The less the amount of data I could get directly from SQL the better.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Power Query for Excel](https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/) for larger data sets.  It stores the data in a compressed, columnar store instead of just writing to a worksheet.

Comment: I tried to search for a way that Power Query could help me the way I needed, but couldn't found something that fit what I wanted Excel to do, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a VBA code to write the Query inside the connection Command Text as it follows:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim X As Long

X = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

'Pass the Parameters values to the Stored Procedure used in the Data Connection
With ThisWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").ODBCConnection
    .CommandText = "select * from TBLexample where Month = " & X 
    ThisWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").ODBCConnection.Refresh
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I just placed a Command Button in the Worksheet, so when the cell is filled with the desired month, the user just press the button and the Tables refresh.